# Validating formGroup which contains asyncValidator while in PENDING state

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Inside a guard, I am trying to check if a form group is valid.

The form group contains an async validator and is in PENDING state when I am trying to check if it is valid inside the canActivate method.

Guard:

```
canActivate()
...
if (formGroup.valid) {
    // do stuff
}
...
```

How can I wait for the async validator to complete?

Answer (score 0):

```
formGroup.statusChanges
  .filter(s=>s==='VALID').take(1).subscribe(()=> /*do stuff...*/)
```